# X11 multiseat configuration

Tags: x11, xorg, vnc, x11vnc, multiseat

I am trying to achieve a Windows-like multiseat effect on my Linux machine with Xorg. My goals are:

- Each user has a single graphical session where they run their graphical applications.
- They can disconnect from their session while keep all their applications running.
- They can access their session from either console (screen + keyboard + mouse) or remote (VNC). Once they connect from one place,other places are disconnected. In short, they can only connect to their session from one place.
- When they switch from console to remote or vice versa, their graphical applications are still running without being interrupted.
- Once a console user disconnect and connect their session using VNC, another user can use the console simultaneously, so the system is running two sessions.
- Users can logon completely using VNC, i.e. showing the display manager over VNC, and creating a session if needed, without using the console.

I tries to access my desktop using x11vnc(1), and it works. However, my screen is shared on both the console and my remote VNC client. This is not what I would like. Also, using x11vnc(1) does not support the multi-user scenario.

I Googled and found that this is a technique called "multiseating", but this technology seems no longer actively used because people no longer need to connect to a shared Unix machine (correct me if I am wrong).

Are there any ways to achieve this? Thanks very much for any help provided.

My specs:

- GNU / Linux with Xorg
- Display manager: SDDM
- Window manager: i3wm
- Session manager: systemd-logind

Comment: are you actually going to have more then one keyboard/mouse/monitor connected, or is it just a single local seat?

Comment: @toppk Sorry for the confusion. I am only going to have a single local seat.

Comment: You could setup all users with a vncserver running on your box, and when they login locally, you just launch a full screen vncviewer that connects to their existing session rather then start a traditional windowmanager.  you can have the vncserver run with NeverShared which will ensure the last connection has full control.

Comment: @toppk Thank you. This could work, but I worry if it will introduce a lot of overhead (VNC protocol / network overhead even on loopback / how about rendering and GPU acceleration?)

Comment: There is an X11 application that is still maintained called x11vnc  that can proxy real X session to remote.  The setup will be a little more complicated, as you will need to give a separate VT to each X display, but I think you can achieve the same result, then you need a login manager that knows to switch to the right vt depending on the login information.

Comment: Since when is Windows multi-seat?

Comment: You're not after multiseat. You're after persistent sessions. As mentioned above, VNC would do this, but VNC is only slightly better at remote session performance than plain old X11 forwarding. It's nowhere near a native desktop experience, even when connecting via the localhost. You will need a GPU that can be split up or multiple GPUs and a desktop streaming application to get as close as possible to a local user's experience. The streaming app will also provide sound, if that's needed.